# First order trigonometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

How can I proceed to solve the following differential equation?

\begin{equation}
   \frac{dy}{dt} + a\cos(y) = u,
\qquad
y(0)=0
\end{equation}

Where $a$ and $u$ are positive constants. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a separable variable differential equation…

Comment: It matters quite a bit whether $a > u$ or $u > a$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog It is assumed that $u>a$.